# Is there something wrong with this definition of principal bundle?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fibre-bundles, principal-bundles

My book is Connections, Curvature, and Characteristic Classes by Loring W. Tu (I'll call this Volume 3), a sequel to both Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology by Loring W. Tu and Raoul Bott (Volume 2) and An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu (Volume 1).

I refer to [Section 27.1 (part 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VA3gA.png), [Section 27.1 (part 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bfszu.png) and [Section 27.1 (part 3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e53TS.png).

I believe there's something wrong with the definition of principal bundle.

**Firstly, I would like to make the following points.** My questions are **given at the end of this post**, and these points provide the context for the questions. These points are my assumptions and observations.

1. I believe the book has no explicit definition for an action to be "transitive" and neither does Volume 1. I think this is okay for the book since Proposition 27.6 is not (explicitly) used later on in the book.
2. Anyway, for a set $S$ (not necessarily manifold) and a group $H$ (not necessarily Lie group) and a right action of $H$ on $S$ (not necessarily free), $\alpha: S \times H \to S$, I assume the definition that $\alpha$ is "transitive" is the one on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action_(mathematics)#Types_of_actions) and assume this is equivalent to "$S$ is non-empty, and for each $s \in S$, the map $\alpha_s : H \to S, \alpha_s(h) = \mu(s,h)$, is surjective".
3. Tu's definition of principal $G$-bundle doesn't say anything (explicitly) about $\mu$ to be transitive, fiber-preserving or *anything* of the sort, but *whichever are true* might be deduced somehow deduced from Tu's definition. I guess the alternative is that Tu made a mistake in the definition of principal $G$-bundle.
4. I actually notice that for each $U \in \mathfrak 
   U$, while we are given an explicit action $\sigma_U: $$(U \times G)$$ \times G \to U \times G$, $\sigma_U((x,h),g)=(x,hg)$, there is no mention of what the action $\zeta_U: P_U \times G \to P_U$ is, where $P_U := \pi^{-1}(U)$. I really think the text is unclear here. I think the text should've said something like "$G$ acts on $U \times G$ (in the way of $\sigma_U$), and then $G$ acts on $\pi^{-1}(U)$ in such a way that $\phi_U$ is $G$-equivariant." Otherwise, it seems kinda weird that you just say a map is equivariant even though you haven't declared the existence of an action on *both* domain and range. It just seems that *somehow*, for each $U \in \mathfrak U$, the action $\mu$ on $P$ induces  actions $\zeta_U$ on $P_U$.

   - 4.1: Probably, there should be some prior proposition that starts with "given a map $f: N \to M$ and action $\zeta$ by $G$ on $N$ we can define an action $\sigma$ by $G$ on $M$" or that starts with "given a map $f: N \to M$ and action $\sigma$ by $G$ on $M$ we can define an action $\zeta$ by $G$ on $N$" and then the next part would be "that makes $f$ equivariant" and then there might be another proposition or some exercise that says that the defined $\zeta$ or $\sigma$ is unique. I'm thinking of something similar to [the pullback metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold#The_pullback_metric).
5. I'm expecting something like, for the action $\mu: P \times G \to P$, we get that

   - 5.1. $\mu(P_x \times G) \subseteq P_x$ (fiber-preserving) and $\mu(P_U \times G) \subseteq P_U$ (trivializing-open-subset-preserving) such that we can define, respectively,  maps $\mu_x: P_x \times G \to P_x$ and $\mu_U: P_U \times G \to P_U$. These turn out to be actions, probably smooth actions.
   - 5.2. Each $\mu_x$ in (5.1) is transitive. (Well, this is what Proposition 27.6 says.)
   - 5.3. $\zeta_U = \mu_U$: Each $\mu_U$ in (5.1) is the action $\zeta_U$ used to determine whether or not $\phi_U$ is $G$-equivariant
6. I really believe there's at least one of the following here:

   - 6.1. ambiguity or implicit relationship between $\mu$ and $\zeta_U$'s,
   - 6.2. implicit rule about uniqueness or existence of an action (in this case $\zeta_U$'s) on domain of a map (the $\phi_U$'s) that makes a map equivariant given an action (the $\sigma_U$'s) on the range
   - 6.3. circular reasoning or circular definitions or something that need to be remedied either by some assumption $\mu$ preserves fibers or trivializing open subsets or by first defining smooth compatible local actions, the $\zeta_U$'s on the $P_U$'s, that make $\phi_U$'s equivariant and then later deducing a global action $\mu$ on $P$

---

**Question 1**: Is this definition of principal $G$-bundle missing some details, such as any of the following?

- 1.A. Any notion (explicit or implicit) of fiber-preservation or trivializing-open-subset-preservation of the action $\mu: P \times G \to P$
- 1.B. Any explicit mention of the relationship between the actions $\zeta_U: P_U \times G \to P_U$ and the action $\mu$
- 1.C. Any mention of some kind of proposition that tells us the $\zeta_U$'s, which may or may not be related to $\mu$, are unique (provided $\phi_U$ bijective equivariant and $\sigma_U$ given as such)

**Question 2**:  If not then, how do we deduce any of (1.A), (1.B), (1.C) ?

**Question 3**: Which of (5.1),(5.2) or (5.3) are true, and why?

**Question 4**: Can we just omit $\mu$ in the definition and then just later make a proposition about $\mu$ in the following way?

I'm thinking we instead **first** define that for each $U \in \mathfrak U$, $G$ acts on $U \times G$ on the right, still by the given $\sigma_U$ and then we say that $G$ acts on $\pi^{-1}(U)$ by some smooth right action $\zeta_U$ (I guess we don't have to include free or transitive since $\sigma_U$ is free and transitive and then freedom and transitivity are preserved under bijective equivariant or whatever), where $\zeta_U$

- i. satisfies some compatibility condition like $\zeta_U|_{U \cap V} = \zeta_V|_{U \cap V}$ for all $V \in \mathfrak V$
- ii. makes $\phi_U$ is $G$-equivariant.

**Later**, we can make a propositions

- **Lemma A**. $\phi_U$ is $G$-equivariant if and only if the $\zeta_U$ is given by $$\zeta_U(e,g) = \phi_U^{-1}(\sigma_U(\phi_U(e),g)) = \phi_U^{-1} \circ \sigma_U \circ ([\phi_U \circ \alpha_U] \times \beta_U) \circ (e,g), \tag{A*}$$ where $\alpha_U: \pi^{-1}(U) \times G \to \pi^{-1}(U)$ and $\beta_U: \pi^{-1}(U) \times G \to G$ are projection maps. (In this case, I guess $\alpha_U$ is the smooth trivial action by $G$ on $\pi^{-1}(U)$.)

  - **Exercise A.i**. Check that $\zeta_U$ in $(A*)$ is a smooth, right, free and transitive (regular) action by $G$ on $\pi^{-1}(U)$.
  - **Exercise A.ii**. Check that $\zeta_U$ in $(A*)$ satisfies the above compatibility condition.
  - **Equivalent Definition A.1**. We use **Lemma A**, **Exercise A.i** and **Exercise A.ii** to say instead that $\zeta_U$ is given by ($A*$).
- **Theorem B**. $G$ globally acts on $P$ by some (smooth) right, free and transitive global action $\mu$ that turns out to be from collecting all the local actions, the $\zeta_U$'s, together: $\mu(p,g):=\zeta_U(p,g)$ for $p \in \pi^{-1}(U)$ for any $U \in \mathfrak U$, which is well-defined either by the compatibility condition assumption on $\zeta_U$'s in the original definition, where we don't yet know the formula for $\zeta_U$ or by **Exercise A.ii**, if we use $\zeta_U$ given by ($A*$).
- **Corollary C1**. $\mu$ is trivializing-open-subset-preserving
- **Corollary C2**. $\mu$ is fiber-preserving

**Update: Question 5**: What is the relationship between the collections $\{Orbit(p)\}_{p \in P}$ of orbits and $\{P_x\}_{x \in M}$ of fibers, and do these two help at all for any the previous questions? I believe that a certain relationship, described below, would imply that Tu's definition is not missing fiber-preserving because fiber-preserving can be deduced. The following bullet points provide the context for question 5 and are part of effort toward answering Question 5 and are part of effort toward answering the previous questions.

- 5.A. I actually notice that each of the collections is a partition of $P$.
- 5.B. I read on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action_(mathematics)#Orbits_and_stabilizers) "Every orbit is an invariant subset of X on which G acts transitively." Ignoring the invariant part, I understand this to mean that for any right action, free or not, transitive or not, $\mu: P \times G \to P$ (in general, not necessarily for the one in the definition of principal bundle. Here, $P$ is just a set, and $G$ is just a group), we have that for each $x \in P$, $\mu(Orbit(x) \times G) \subseteq Orbit(x)$ such that we can define a map, which might be an action, $\mu_{Orbit(x)}: Orbit(x) \times G \to Orbit(x)$ that turns out indeed to be a right action on $Orbit(x)$ that is additionally transitive. Assuming I understand this correctly, I was able to prove this.
- 5.C. Based on the Willie Wong's comment and on (5.A) and (5.B), it seems there's some relationship between (now going back to defining a principal bundle) $Orbit(p)$ and $P_x$ for $\pi(p)=x \in M$ or something like that. The following is all I can think of:

  - 5.C.1. I notice $p \in Orbit(p) \cap P_x$. Whenever 2 elements of the same partition intersect, they are equal. However, $Orbit(p)$ and $P_x$ belong to different partitions...Well, I assume the partitions are different. They could turn out to be equal.
  - 5.C.2. Perhaps $\mu$ free implies that $Orbit(a)=Orbit(b)$ if or only if $\pi(a)=\pi(b)$.
  - 5.C.3. For each $x \in M$ and for each $y \in P_x$, we have a map $\mu_y: G \to P$, $\mu_y(g) := \mu(y,g)$, with image $im(\mu_y) = \mu_y(G)$ $=Orbit(y)$. Each $\mu_y$ turns out to be injective because $\mu$ is free.
  - 5.C.4. For each $x \in M$ and for each $y \in P_x$, the set inclusion $\mu(Orbit(y) \times G) \subseteq Orbit(y)$. This set inclusion allows us to define a map $\mu_{Orbit(y)}: Orbit(y) \times G \to Orbit(y)$, $\mu_{Orbit(y)}(x,g) := \mu(x,g)$. By (5.B), each $\mu_{Orbit(y)}$ is a transitive right action.

    - 5.C.4.1. If we somehow have that $Orbit(y)=P_x$ for each $y \in P_x$, then the set inclusion $\mu(Orbit(y) \times G) \subseteq Orbit(y)$ is precisely $\mu(P_x \times G) \subseteq P_x$, which shows $\mu$ is fiber-preserving. I guess that $\mu$ is free is supposed to somehow show that $Orbit(y)=P_x$.

Comment: I didn't read your whole question, just the beginning. But for point 1, doesn't Tu say that the trivialization maps are $G$-equivariant? This means that $G$ is fibre preserving, no? For point 2: no, the map $\mu_x: G \to M$ is in general not surjective. Transitivity means that $\mu_x: G \to P_x$ is surjective. The fact that in the local trivialization $G$ acts on the fibre (which is identified with $G$) by right multiplication implies that $G$ must act transitively on fibres. (A group acts transitively on itself.)

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks. For point 2, I wasn't talking about this particular $\mu$, $M$ or $G$. I was talking in about actions in general. Am I still wrong? For point 1, the rest of my question includes how we can discuss $G$-equivariance even though we don't know what the $\zeta_U$'s are. It seems like the $\zeta_U$'s are supposed to be restrictions (of both domain and range) on $\mu$ assuming the restrictions are possible i.e. $\mu$ is trivializing-open-subset-preserving, but how do we know this? If you say you deduce $\mu$ is trivializing-open-subset-preserving from $G$-equivariance, then

Comment: @WillieWong how do you know anything about $\mu$ from the $\zeta_U$'s? What I propose in Question 4 includes an explicit relationship between $\mu$ and the $\zeta_U$'s.

Comment: @WillieWong For "The fact that in the local trivialization"...please be specific $G$ has actions $\mu$ on $P$, $\zeta_U$ on $P_U$ and $\sigma_U$ on $U \times G$. You seem to be applying your deductions about $\zeta_U$ to $\mu$. My post includes asking about the relationship between $\zeta_U$ and $\mu$. I really believe the text makes an implicit assumption about such relationship.

Comment: @WillieWong Actually for point 2, what do you mean by transitivity? This is what I understand: For a set $S$, a group $H$ and a right action $\alpha: S \times H \to S$, transitive or not, we have a map $\alpha_x: H \to S$ for each $x \in S$. $\alpha_x$ is not necessarily surjective or injective. We can additionally define $\tilde{\alpha_x}: H \to Orbit(x)$ as $\alpha_x$ with range restricted to its image, which is $Orbit(x)$. That $\alpha$ is transitive is equivalent to the surjectivity of each $\alpha_x$ and equivalent to $Orbit(x)=S$ for each $x \in S$.

Comment: @WillieWong However, since you thought I was referring specifically to $\mu$ in the definition for principal bundle, I actually notice that both the collections $\{Orbit(p)\}_{p \in P}$ and $\{\pi^{-1}(x)\}_{x \in M}$ are partitions of $P$. Are you suggesting some relationship between $Orbit(p)$ and $\pi^{-1}(x)$ for $\pi(p)=x$? Well I notice $p \in Orbit(p) \cap \pi^{-1}(x)$. That's about it.

Comment: @WillieWong In relation to my last comment, I edited the post to include another question.

Comment: WHy can't you ask one question at a time? :O Please :( After you name the books, you start suddenly with "I believe the book has no explicit definition for an action $\mu$ to be "transitive" and neither does Volume 1. I think this is okay for the book since Proposition 27.6 is not (explicitly) used later on in the book." What? :O  It would be easier to get the setup if you can start by saying what you want to talk about.

Comment: If I understand correctly, in the first part of the question, you are asking **if the action of $G$ on $P$** in the set up of  a principal $G$-bundle $\pi:P\rightarrow M$ **is transitive or not**... My answer is NO... it is not true (according to any definition) that the action is transitive... It only means the action is transitive on the fibres of the map $\pi:P\rightarrow M$; that is, for each $x\in M$, the action of $G$ on $\pi^{-1}(x)$ is transitive... Is this what you are asking?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Thanks for replying. I'm going to edit (2) to use different variables. I was talking about general actions not specifically the one for principal bundles

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik The questions are related and most of these questions supposedly serve a dual purpose of 1. asking the question and 2. showing effort toward answering  and even further clarifying the previous question(s). I think of avoiding situation like: I ask one question, and then someone answers and then when I ask the next question, either 1. the answer to the previous question turns out wrong, 2. There was some misunderstanding or 3. one question gets closed as a duplicate

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Edited. It sounds like you were referring to (1.1) rather than "Question 1". Do I misunderstand? The bullet points numbered 1-6 and the subbullet points are not my questions I have edited to clarify this. These bullet points provide context for the questions. My first question is given later on in the post. You said "It would be easier to get the setup if you can start by saying what you want to talk about." That's what I hoped the title would be. I'll edit a little more.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Edited more. I deleted (1.1) and (1.2). I never intended to ask if $\mu$ is transitive.

Comment: Thanks for taking care in clarifying the concern... Edited version looks much better and cleaner... I will respond accordingly..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Oh, thank you for saying that. You don't have to thank me for anything. I'm the one asking the favor. Anything you have to say is purely out of generosity.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Any response please?

Comment: I somehow forgot about this.. It's 12:20 AM here... The first thing i would do tomorrow is to respond here... :) :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Anything please? Haha

Comment: @SeleneAuckland I am sorry. I do not remember the question. I will respond in two days...

Comment: There are so many things to discuss :) what do you mean by fibre preserving action ?? ”1.A. Any notion (explicit or implicit) of fiber-preservation or trivializing-open-subset-preservation of the action :×→“ Coming to 1.B, the map $\mu_U$ is restriction of the action map... They didn’t mention but it is understood

Comment: It might be difficult to write down all responses with out knowing what you have digested... we can move this discussion to chat... you can also contact me